# Mass Emails Getting Rejected by Google

Tags: gmail, html-email, google-apps, email-spam, mass-emails

I need help automating mass emails I'm sending daily.

I'm trying to send out automated mass emails through a Gmail account (My Business uses Google Apps). I built a Java program that allows me to enter my credentials (gmail username & password), Subject Line, Email List, and enter is a body template. The program then sends out emails one at a time to each of the contacts which are in a comma delimited list. This isn't spam as I'm getting the users to submit their email address.

I got this Mail Delivery Message today: "Technical details of permanent failure: Message rejected." I read that Google will only allow a maximum of 100 recipients to any message through its smtp gateway - and there's a maximum of 500 messages in any 24 hr period.

I need a new strategy. How do I build a program to automate sending of ~100-200 emails a day?  Do I need to be buying IP's, SMTP Servers, write a new PHP application? I need a place to start because this is out of my scope.

Answer (score 3):

Gmail is not designed for email marketing as you have seen. In the past I have used a Google App Engine account for sending tens to hundreds of thousands of emails (because that was where the domain was managed), but that can be a pain to manage.

You could consider using a service that specializes in email marketing. I have heard good things about [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/) and [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/). Plus MailChimp can integrate into Google Apps.

Answer (score 0):

We use www.authsmtp.com but I was looking at switching to Google when we switch to Google Apps in the near future. I'll have to drill in a bit more. IN the meantime, give authsmtp a try.

Answer (score 0):

Google specifically rejects this type of behavior/use of their system. https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69585

I would suggest trying a system that is built for this type of activity such as [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) or [Aweber](http://www.aweber.com/).